# Lyx can't generate pdf for CJK-containing document

Tags: lyx, texlive, cjk

I use Lyx on Windows 10.

I did what this link asks me to do.

```
https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/Chinese
```

I added this to document preamble.

```
\usepackage{cjk}
\usepackage{arphic}
\usepackage{latex-cjk-all}
```

I changed Language->Endocing->Other to "Unicode (CJK) (utf8)"

I change Fonts->CJK to either blank or "gkai" but neither works.

Error messages include

```
LaTex Error: Command \CJKcaption already defined 
And so many other similar erorrs that say CJK something something already defined

LaTex Error: File `arphic.sty' not found.
```

How can I fix this problem?

User "K J" said "if it says "not found" you need to verify all the TeX dependencies are up-to-date and loaded in the correct folders which lyx usually will check. the fact you have "already defined" constantly suggests you may need to remove and replace some modules but that advise is best gained from lyx support direct"

but I don't know "correct folders which lyx usually will check" and also I don't know what "TeX dependencies" mean and I don't know "remove and replace some modules". What should I do exactly?

Comment: Could you please add the LyX file to the post? Note that a LyX file is a text file, so you can open it with a text editor and paste it here. Try to make the example file as minimal as possible.